# Problem with loop printing csv contents in php

Tags: php, debugging

This snippet just about works :|

I can spit out all of the array data, but what I want is to be able to print out the data column by column.

```
function processCSV()
{
    global $uploadFile;
    $loadLocationCsvUrl = fopen($uploadFile,"r");   
    if ($loadLocationCsvUrl <> false)
    {
        while ($locationFile = fgetcsv($loadLocationCsvUrl, ','))
        {
            $csvCols = array(
                             'country' => $locationFile[9],
                             'open' => $locationFile[4],
                             'officeid' => $locationFile[2]
                             );
            foreach($csvCols as $locationData)
            {
                if ($locationData == '') {
                    echo "<p>" . "blank" . "</p>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<p>" . $locationData . "</p>";        
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    fclose($loadLocationCsvUrl);
}
processCSV();
```

I thought this would work:

```
echo "<p>" . $locationData['country'] . "</p>";
```

But if I do that I see a incorrectly formatted page, like the below (uploaded screenshot).

http://www.imageupload.org/?d=9C676F041

---

I managed to work this out with a different implementation, I switched to a 2d array, the table rendering was never the issue it was obtaining the data.

```
<?php
function processCSV()
{
    global $uploadFile;
    $loadLocationCsvUrl = fopen($uploadFile,"r");   
    if ($loadLocationCsvUrl <> false)
    {
        while ($locationFile = fgetcsv($loadLocationCsvUrl, ','))
        {
            $officeId = $locationFile[2];
            $country = $locationFile[9];
            $open = $locationFile[4];
            echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$officeId</td>";
                    echo "<td>$country</td>";
                    echo "<td>$open</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
    fclose($loadLocationCsvUrl);
}
processCSV();
?>
```

Thank you for responding and sorry if I wasted anybodies time.

Comment: What happened to good old debuging and trial and error (and echo). stackoverflow.com is not a debugger!

Comment: @user752336 your image is broken. Can you just upload to SO directly?

Comment: @Itay Moav Appreciate your commentary and sarcasm the Internet would not be the same place.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the CSV file please.

Comment: Please put your answer in an *answer* and click the check mark to accept it; only then we can see that your question is solved and no longer needs our attention.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to display the output colum-wise. In that case a `<table>` is the intended markup. But I would first simplify your code:

```
// read in
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($uploadFile));

// output
print "<table>";
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    print <<<HTML
      <tr>
         <td>$row[9]</td>
         <td>$row[4]</td>         
         <td>$row[2]</td>
      </tr>
HTML;
}
```

If you don't use the associative array keys for the columns, then there's no point in creating them.

Answer (score 0):

<p> is a block element, so each successive one goes to a new line by design. You can set 'display: inline;' in your css if you want, but then why use <p>?

You could use an inline element like <span> or use 'float: left' to make a block element behave as you want.

That's assuming the data isn't appropriate for tabulation.

Answer (score 0):

make a parent table then tr and td,

now, inside this td, make a table and print a column of td-trs

then close this table

print a new td in parent

repeat a table of one column trs

example....

```
<table><tr><td>
    <table>
    <tr><td>col1stuff1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>col1stuff2</td><tr>
    <tr><td>col1stuff3</td><tr>
    </table>
</td><td>
    <table>
    <tr><td>col2stuff1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>col2stuff2</td><tr>
    <tr><td>col2stuff3</td><tr>
    </table>
</td><td>
    <table>
    <tr><td>col3stuff1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>col3stuff2</td><tr>
    <tr><td>col3stuff3</td><tr>
    </table>
</td></tr></table>
```